# How to save and load the Scene and Gameobject in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a project of cabling in unity and I want to save all the modification that a player does in the scene.

How should i save the game? How can I save my gameobject? I need to serialize my gameobject but I don't know how to do this!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour 
{    
    public Transform player;

    int i;

    void Start ()
    {
        i = 1; 
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Escape))     
        {   
            Pause(); 
        }

    if(player.GetComponent<FirstPersonController>().enabled == false) 
    {
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.UpArrow))
        { 
            Debug.Log ("Up pressed");
            player.transform.position = new Vector3(player.transform.position.x,player.transform.position.y + 1.0f,player.transform.position.z); 
        } 
        else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.DownArrow))
        { 
            Debug.Log ("Down pressed");
            player.transform.position = new Vector3(player.transform.position.x,player.transform.position.y - 1.0f,player.transform.position.z); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serialize and Deserialize Json and Json Array in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239705/serialize-and-deserialize-json-and-json-array-in-unity)

Answer (score 0):

So, I assume that - in another script - you are going to load a new Scene, and you want to maintain the object having the `GameController` script attached to it.

In this case, you can use the [DontDestroyOnLoad()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) call, the trivial form goes like this (just add the `Awake()` function to your class):

```
void Awake()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
}
```

This way, the object won't be destroyed when a new scene is loaded.

In case you want to save data when the game is closed, in order to load them afterwards, [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) are the answer.

Comment: there is no other way for saving  gameobjects ?

Comment: These ones are the solutions that Unity provides out-of-the-box. Custom solutions can be created (like using a database, or an XML), but obviously they are more complex because you have to use your own code.

Comment: because i used  DontDestroyOnLoad() but it didnt work.when i exited from the game ,everythings came like initial scene. i want to save my game

Comment: There's no such method in your question. Adding it could help us addressing the exact problem.